# Term for "people who get easily traumatized"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases

I am surfing over google and dictionary and books but cannot find a term for people who are easily traumatized.

Is there any term for it? Or should we just say like:
She is easily traumatized.

Comment: Do you mean sb who is " touchy" , " irritable" or "crabby" ?  It would be much better if an example were presented inorder to clarify what you want.

Comment: A *snowflake* is pretty close

Comment: In U.S. tort law there is a category of plaintiff known as "the **egg-shell-skull** plaintiff." It refers to someone who may be badly injured by an action that would not seriously harm a person of normal physical and mental resilience. In tort law, the issue is significant, since the foreseeability of harm is often treated as a component in liability—and the question naturally comes up, "Accepting that pushing someone off a low wall constitutes tortious conduct, to what extent is a person liable for the extreme harm that occurs when it turns out that victim of the pushing was Humpty-Dumpty?"

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of applicable terms. *Fragile* is common, and is frequently used for someone prone to mental shocks as well as physical. [Fragile has plenty of synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fragile) like *delicate, frail, weak, flimsy and brittle*, which you can use as the mood takes you.

Comment: Yep, and "emotionally fragile" might be a hair better, to eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

[Sensitive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensitive) works here.

> highly responsive or susceptible: such as
>
> 1. easily hurt or damaged
>
>    - especially : easily hurt emotionally